# Spacing between table caption and table content

Tags: spacing, deluxetable

In my table, there is very less space between the table caption and the table content. How do I custom declare a space in between them?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{deluxetable}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\newcolumntype{s}{>{\columncolor[HTML]{AAACED}} p{3cm}}

\begin{document}
\onecolumngrid
\begin{deluxetable}{c c c }
\tablecaption{Mass fraction yields of isotopes in ejecta and fallback at $t=60$s.\label{simtable}}
\vspace{10pt}
\bigskip
\tablehead{\colhead {Isotopes} & \colhead {Ejecta} & \colhead {Fallback }  }
\startdata
${}^{16}$O & $3.71 \times 10^{-1}$  & $6.43 \times 10^{-1}$  \\ 
${}^{28}$Si & $2.60 \times 10^{-1}$  & $5.40 \times 10^{-2}$  \\


\enddata

\end{deluxetable}

\end{document}
```

I tried \vsapce and \bigskip, but nothing seems to work here. any suggestions?

You need deluxtable.sty to compile the code

Comment: Please edit your question to make your code compilable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how to use the spacing with vspace*{}:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{aastex}





\begin{document}
%\onecolumngrid
\begin{deluxetable}{c c c }
\tablecaption{Mass fraction yields of isotopes in ejecta and fallback at $t=60$s.\label{simtable}\vspace*{40pt}}

\tablehead{\colhead {Isotopes} & \colhead {Ejecta} & \colhead {Fallback } \vspace*{20pt} }
\startdata
${}^{16}$O & $3.71 \times 10^{-1}$  & $6.43 \times 10^{-1}$  \\ 
${}^{28}$Si & $2.60 \times 10^{-1}$  & $5.40 \times 10^{-2}$  \\
\enddata

\end{deluxetable}
\end{document}
```

And the result:[image]

I have removed the \onecolumngrid in this example... but you get how spacing works...

Edit:
here is your example but I don't have the packages and changed it a little

```
\documentclass{aastex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
%\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{comment}
%\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{deluxetable}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

%\newcolumntype{s}{>{\columncolor[HTML]{AAACED}} p{3cm}}

\begin{document}
%\onecolumngrid
\begin{deluxetable}{c c c }
\tablecaption{Mass fraction yields of isotopes in ejecta and fallback at $t=60$s.\label{simtable}\vspace*{40pt}}


\tablehead{\colhead {Isotopes} & \colhead {Ejecta} & \colhead {Fallback } \vspace*{30pt} }
\startdata
${}^{16}$O & $3.71 \times 10^{-1}$  & $6.43 \times 10^{-1}$  \\ 
${}^{28}$Si & $2.60 \times 10^{-1}$  & $5.40 \times 10^{-2}$  \\
\enddata

\end{deluxetable}

\end{document}
```